# Does shutil.copy recognize the tilde (~) character, is there an alternative to the tilde that shutil.copy recognizes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

I'm trying to build a simple python tool that can generate some HTML templates for me on command. I'm trying to make it generic, I basically just want it to copy three files located in a certain directory into the current directory. When I try to grab the files, I use shutil.copy('~/tools/HTML_tools/[files]). I keep getting errors though, it seems like shutil.copy does not recognize the tilde (~) character, but I'm not sure.

I want my program to be runnable from any directory. I've created an alias in .bashrc to run it.

alias genHTML='python3 ~/tools/genHTML/genHTML.py'

I've tried instead doing shutil.copy('/home/' + USER + '/tools/HTML_tools/[files]'), where the USER is a string stored in a text file user.txt. That also didn't work because opening the USER file would have also been dependent on the tilde character, because it is also in a fixed position.

```
from shutil import copy

if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        copy('~/tools/HTML_tools/template.html', './')
        copy('~/tools/HTML_tools/styles.css', './')
        copy('~/tools/HTML_tools/script.js', './')
    except IOError:
        print('It appears something went wrong.')
```

I expect this file to copy into the current directory the files template.html, styles.css, and script.js. Instead I get a FileNotFoundError saying ~/tools/HTML_tools/[files] does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You want to call [`expanduser()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) prior to calling `copy()`.

```
from shutil import copy
import os

tools_dir = os.path.expanduser('~/tools/HTML_tools')
copy(os.path.join(tools_dir, 'template.html'), '.')
```